# How can I, a permanent resident of Canada, get an Emergency UK visa to visit sick nephew?

Tags: visas, uk, canada

This is an emergency. I want to visit my nephew who has been admitted to a Manchester, England hospital where he is on life support equipment. I live in Canada where I am a permanent resident. Nobody is helping me and I don't know where to turn for help. It is so stressful for me.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: And you're a citizen of which country?

Comment: They stopped issuing emergency visas in 2010.  Depending upon your nationality, your immigration status in Canada, and your immigration history you may be able to qualify for one of the premium services.  In all events you need to apply at the one of the Visa Application Centres and your application will be processed in New York.  The VAC will tell you which premium service(s) you qualify for.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be from six years ago and is from [Yahoo! Answers](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091004154206AAed0lx) so suspect for both currency and reliability but I regret the indication is that you may not have access to a fast-track procedure. It seems to have been written in the context of an enquiry from India but I doubt that is a significant difference in the circumstances.

> "Emergency procedures will only apply to applications in rare situations. The guidelines are very specific regarding what is an emergency.
>
> These reasons are:
>
> • Illness or death of an immediate family member (immediate family members are the applicant's mother, father, brother, sister, husband, wife, son, or daughter).
>   • Emergency medical treatment which includes any persons needing to travel for support (such as a parent caring for an ill child).
>
> There are 4 steps to submit an emergency visa application for the UK.
>   Read the visa application guidance on this website and submit your online application.
>
> Once an online application form has been fully completed, email your online application reference, which starts with GWF005******** to visqry.newdelhi@fco.gov.uk.
>   , marked 'emergency application request'. Your email should explain why the application is eligible for emergency submission.
>
> On receipt of this information the UK Border Agency will assess whether the application meets the criteria and if eligible, the applicant will be given appointment details so they can submit their application at the visa application centre.
>
> All applications will be subject to mandatory checks which will take at least 24 hours to complete. Actual processing times will depend on the unique circumstances of the case."
>
> http://www.ukvac-ua.com/emergency.aspx
>   http://ukinindia.fco.gov.uk/en/visas-for...

Comment: The links are broken, and are on the original page.